# Laptop Charger Not Recognised Properly on Samsung NP900X3F

Tags: power-management, suspend, battery, samsung

Firstly thanks for your time.
Secondly, having an issue with my power charger on my Samsung Series 9 NP900X3F.

When I boot into Ubuntu with the charger plugged in it recognises it as charging. When I unplug the charger after this it is still says it is charging.

If I suspend in Ubuntu then plug/unplug during this suspended state it recognises it, but not during normal running.

If I knew a little more I'm sure I could grab logs and find out what the difference between wake on suspend and normal running is, but alas I need help!

I also am having issues with my keyboard backlight via the fn keys, but that I care about far less.

Thank you very much.

Linux mikey-900X3F 3.12.0-031200rc1-generic #201309161735 SMP Mon Sep 16 21:38:21 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

(I upgraded my kernel version to remove heinous horizontal artefacts I was getting)

Happy to list more info about my system, ima bit of a noob.
I did try searching however I can't find any questions at all about my system or related models with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade your kernel again.  Saucy Salamander is out now and it should fix this.  It did for me with my np900x3e, though I now have a new problem, that my laptop no longer suspends.  So do so at your own risk.

Comment: thanks this did the trick (thought I responded to this earlier!). my suspend works perfectly. the only problem I seem to have now is my backlighting on the keyboard. but I don't particularly care about that feature.